# vimeo - how do i add a custom control bar?

Tags: javascript, actionscript

I've been searching all over the place for some code to add a custom progress/control bar to embedded vimeo videos. An example of what I'd like to do is the progress bar at the bottom: http://www.5by.com/amazing-timelapses/posts/9LZ/boston-layer-lapse

any suggestions?

thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it with javascript, at least that is how that page works.

```
<button onclick="Player.togglePlayPause()" />
```

Comment: If you hover over the video the vimeo progress bar will appear and then there's also the custom progress bar. how can I add a custom progress bar?

Comment: That twas my first vimeo video I saw in years. Just look at the source code; thats how I found the code for the button.

Comment: The Beauty of no ads!! I've found quite a bit on the Web about pause, mute, etc but nothing about an additional slider, is the slider Flash?